Keyboard Accelerators Not Working Without Developer Mode in Windows 10 for WinUI 3 App
I'm developing a WinUI 3 application and using keyboard accelerators for various actions. However, I've noticed that some key combinations don't work as expected on Windows 10 unless Developer Mode is enabled. Interestingly, the same key combinations work perfectly fine on Windows 11 without requiring Developer Mode.
For example:
Key Combination 1: alt+shift+f12
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there specific settings or configurations in Windows 10 that might be causing this behavior? Is there a workaround or a known solution to make the accelerators work without enabling Developer Mode?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried and What I Expected:
I implemented keyboard accelerators in my WinUI 3 app and tested them on both Windows 10 and Windows 11. I expected the accelerators to work seamlessly across both operating systems without requiring special configurations.
What Actually Happened:
On Windows 10, certain key combinations only worked when Developer Mode was enabled. Without Developer Mode, these combinations did not trigger the expected actions. On Windows 11, the accelerators worked as intended regardless of Developer Mode.
Steps Tried:
Verified the implementation of the accelerators.
Tested with different key combinations.
Checked permissions and configurations in Windows 10.
Despite these steps, the issue persisted in Windows 10 unless Developer Mode was activated.

Not sure if this might be related but according to the docs: "WinUI 3 works downlevel to Windows 10 October 2018 Update (Version 1809, OS build 17763".

What is your Windows 10 version?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT It is windows 10 pro Version: 22H2 OS build: 19045.5011 Experience  : Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0

This is indeed an unexpected behavior. I suggest you submit it here https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues
